# populate user data first then filter based on user First and lastName directly from query

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to filter Record based on user First name and last Name while populating data of user through user ID , I am just trying to do it directly from Query , Is it possible to populate and filter directly through query

here is code snipped

```
if(filter) {

            where.$or = [
                { "sender.fname": { $regex: String(filter), $options: "i" } },
                { "sender.lname": { $regex: String(filter), $options: "i" } },
                {
                    $expr: {
                        $regexMatch: {
                            input: { $concat: ["$sender.fname", " ", "$sender.lname"] },
                            regex: filter,
                        }
                    }
                }
            ];
            
        }
/* All records with Pagination */
        const data_arr = await friend_requests
            .find(where)
            .select("-reciever -request_status")
            .populate({
                path: "sender",
                select: { fname: 1, lname: 1, email: 1, photo: 1, about: 1, hikeExperience: 1, totalHikes:1 }
            })
            .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
            .limit(pageLimit)
            .exec()
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
```